# Liquid - How do I setup liquid template locally

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dotliquid, liquid-template

How do I set up [Liquid Templates](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) locally? Suppose, I have this liquid template and I want to run this locally.

```
{%- assign deviceList = content.devices | Split: ', ' -%}
{
    "fullName": "{{content.firstName | Append: ' ' | Append: content.lastName}}",
    "firstNameUpperCase": "{{content.firstName | Upcase}}",
    "phoneAreaCode": "{{content.phone | Slice: 1, 3}}",
     "devices" : [
       {%- for device in deviceList -%}
         {%- if forloop.Last == true -%}
         "{{device}}"
         {%- else -%}
         "{{device}}",
          {%- endif -%}
       {%- endfor -%}
    ]
}
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Logic Apps uses the [DotLiquid](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid) implementation for working with liquid templates which has a couple of [differences](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-for-Designers) from the original implementation, specifically the [filter and output casing](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-for-Designers#filter-and-output-casing).

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a tool (like a CLI) which is built around dotliquid but there is one for with the original ruby implementation - [liquid-cli](https://github.com/pbrisbin/liquid-cli) - which I was able to use to test liquid templates locally.

To get the CLI to work, you would have to use the ruby casing (snake_case) instead of the C# naming conventions (PascalCase) for it to work and then change it back when using it in logic apps.

Answer (score 1):

I just started as well and at the beginning I was using https://github.com/skastberg/LiquidTransformation which was ok for basic stuff but had some issues if some filters/tags.

But in the end i just created a logic app to test and a free integration account.

Comment: What filters/tags did you have issues with? I am looking if I can improve it. Remember to use capitals when using the functions